# multi-search box with two submit buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'd like to have an input field with two submit buttons. Type a search in and click either Google or Wikipedia and have my terms search the appropriate site. However I am not sure I'm using the right terminology for this (or if it's even possible). I've found plenty of ways to do it with a drop down list, or radio buttons, but each of these requires 1-3 clicks between typing in the search and clicking the appropriate button.

Ideally I'd like to accomplish this without javascript/jquery but I suspect that's not actually possible. Any suggestions?

```js
function OnSubmitForm()
{
  if(document.pressed == 'Google')
  {
   document.searchform.action ="http://www.google.com/search";
  }
  else
  if(document.pressed == 'Wikipedia')
  {
    document.searchform.action ="http://www.wikipedia.org/search-redirect.php";
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
```

```html
<form name="searchform" method="get" onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm();" action="http://www.google.com/search">
<input type="text" name="q" size="20" value="">
<input type="submit" name="operation" onclick="document.pressed=this.value" value="Google">
<input type="submit" name="operation" onclick="document.pressed=this.value" value="Wikipedia" class="searchButton">
</form>
```

So the google portion of the code works, but I am doing something wrong with the Javascript to change the action to search wikipedia if the wikipedia button is clicked.

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. We are not here to build your system for you, nor design it for you, not critique your design. Once you have some actual code, we'll maybe help try fix it, but that's about it.

Comment: Fair enough. Let me try and get the code I've got working partially again and I'll edit this post.

Comment: *"Ideally I'd like to accomplish this without javascript/jquery but I suspect that's not actually possible."* - pretty much, the HTML form will only be submitted to the `action` without some font-end JS to jiggle about with that value (or by using buttons with onclick events, which are again JS) you're a bit stuck.

Comment: Would you like to perform the search and get the result or do you want to actually redirect the user to the search itself? if you want to gather the results only, then your way is to use the official google search API.. For google. For wikipedia.. Well.. Not sure :P

Comment: I just want to perform the search... that is send them to google or wikipedia ...

Answer (score 1):

This is very possible with jQuery ... you would end up with something like ...

```
$("#googleButton").on('click', function() { /* navigation with search criteria */ });
$("#wikipediaButton").on('click', function() { /* navigation with search criteria */ });
```

Comment: Within the code, you can gather the inputs and format the navigation.